# Use Laravel routeNotifcationForMail() to send to multiple emails addresses?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, traits

I'm using the `Notifiable` trait on my Model.

User has comma-separated list of subscribed emails (string).

The documentation and my background reading suggests that this will only route to a single email address.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Route notifications for the mail channel.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForMail()
    {
        return $this->email_address;
    }
}
```

[Laravel 5.3 Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait)

I've also read [Matt Stauffer on Notifications](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-new-notification-system-in-laravel-5-3) but can't see an answer there.

My `NotificationClass->toMail()` is as follows.

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param Store $store
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function toMail(User $user)
{
    return (new MailMessage)->view('notifications.emails.activity-roundup', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: You either have User instance (with one user and one email most likely) or you have a collection of Users and you can simply chain and send those notifications off. I kind of do not get what is being asked here.

Comment: Not quite. As I've said single user can have multiple notification addresses.These are currently de-normalised.

`me@domain.com, sales@domain.com, audit-trail@domain.com, etc@different-domain.com`

Comment: Now I understand. I will think about it and come back. Using 5.3 right?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, absolutely spot-on didn't realise 5.3 had it's own tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want code below since you can send array ([see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php#L49-L50)):

```
/**
 * Route notifications for the mail channel.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function routeNotificationForMail()
{
    return $this->emailsToArray();
}

private function emailsToArray() {
    if (is_null($this->email_addresses)) {
        return $this->email; //default email
    }
    //perform more checks that you need
    return array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->email_addresses))
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the trait expects a string not an array as far as I can tell.

Comment: Did you try? Did it error out? Trait can not expect anything there is no strict typing.

Comment: It only sends to the first email address.

Comment: Show me your notification `toMail()` method

Comment: How do you know that its only send to one email? It uses bcc for other emails, can you verify? Also try to forcefully add debug line here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php#L48 with `\Log::info($message->to);` and see whats spit into log.

Comment: I'll check it out, only receiving one email and have 3 addresses set in the user table.

Comment: This is correct, I had the Notifications queue on SQS being processed by two apps, staging and local and my changes on local were working but staging was faster at processing the Notifications with the old implementation.

Comment: Every detail counts, I didnt even know you use queues... next time be specific...

Comment: Same problem here with laravel 8, only the first address in the array receives the mail